# Run command as other user in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I try to run command as other user in Ubuntu. But it cannot find the command.

```
$ sudo su - hbase -c "echo $JAVA_HOME"
/usr/local/jdk

$ sudo su - hbase -c "echo $PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/jdk/bin

$ sudo su - hbase -c "java -version"
-su: java: command not found

$ sudo su - hbase -c "/usr/local/jdk/bin/java -version"
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

I tested in centos, there is no problem. I don't know why? And how can I run java in other user?

My `JAVA_HOME` is set in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and Ubuntu version is ubuntu server 14.04.1.

Actually, I'm trying to start/stop hbase in hadoop user in

```
$ sudo su - hbase -c "/usr/local/hbase-1.1.5/bin/hbase-daemon.sh stop regionserver"
no regionserver to stop because no pid file /tmp/hbase-hbase-regionserver.pid
```

And this error is because it cannot get my environment `export HBASE_PID_DIR="/data/hadoop/run/hbase"`, which I set in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

I did more tests, first, I added `export ENVTEST=hello` to `/etc/bash.bashrc`, then, did the following tests.

```
$ echo $ENVTEST

$ sudo su - hbase -c "echo $ENVTEST"

$ source /etc/bash.bashrc
$ sudo su - hbase -c "echo $ENVTEST"
hello
```

It seems like, when you do `sudo su - hbase -c "echo $ENVTEST"`, it is using the my user environment instead of hbase.

Comment: Why did you exclude the dash on the second command?

Comment: My mistake, I tried both, but only post without dash one

Comment: it will be informative to try these with single-quotes: `sudo su - hbase -c 'echo $JAVA_HOME'` and `sudo su - hbase -c 'echo $PATH'`. it should show that `/usr/local/jdk/bin` is not in root's path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like `/usr/local/jdk/bin` is not in `hbase`'s `PATH`. add `/usr/local/jdk/bin` to `PATH` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/home/hbase/.bashrc`.

because of the double-quotes, this test doesn't do what you might think:

```
sudo su - hbase -c "echo $PATH"
```

`$PATH` inside the double-quotes has its value substituted in before `sudo su - hbase -c` runs.

try these tests out:

```
sudo su - hbase -c "echo `whoami`"
sudo su - hbase -c 'echo `whoami`'
sudo su - hbase -c 'echo $JAVA_HOME'
sudo su - hbase -c 'echo $PATH'
```

Comment: Oh, right! But how can I let hbase to use `/etc/bash.bashrc` as the environment?

Comment: it might already, or you might try: `sudo ln -s /etc/bash.bashrc /home/hbase/.bashrc`